# sails js / waterline / mysql table name and table prefix

Tags: javascript, mysql, sails.js, waterline

I am new to sails.js. I want to select all record from a table. How to use .find() .

Specially how waterline will know from which table i want data ? Because we are not mentioning any table name in model. I know there is .query(). But is this possible within waterline basic create / update / find / delete method ?

Another question how to use prefix for table name in sails.js ? Like i want to use sails_product as table name.

Comment: The model name should have the table name `tableName` attribute to make it easy for the controller to use different query related methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am new to sails.js. I want to select all record from a table. How to use .find() .

If your model name is, for example, `Book`, you'd select all `Book` records with

```
Book.find()
    .exec(function(err, books) {
        if (err) return res.serverError();
        console.log(books); // 'books' is an array of the found records
    })
```

> Specially how waterline will know from which table i want data ? Because we are not mentioning any table name in model. I know there is .query(). But is this possible within waterline basic create / update / find / delete method ?

Yes, it's possible. You don't have to deal with table names and such at all with waterline, all you need is your **model name.** Create, update, delete all work the same way as the `find` example above - so `ModelName.actionName()`.

> Another question how to use prefix for table name in sails.js ? Like i want to use sails_product as table name.

By default, waterline uses the model name lowercased as the corresponding table name. You can, however, overwrite this in your model settings. For example, if you have your model defined in a file called `Book.js`, its contents would look like this:

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        name: {
            type: 'String',
            required: true
        },
        price: {
            type: 'float'
        }
    },

    tableName: 'custom_book_table'

}
```

This way the actual table created in the database will be called `custom_book_table`, while you'll still refer to your model in `find` queries etc. as `Book`.

Here's links to both [Waterline](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs) and [Sails](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/concepts/) docs to get you going. In model/query related issues, I'd definitely search from Waterline docs first.

Comment: great help Fissio. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @pritam, if an answer solve your problem, you should consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so the user that gave you the best answer is rewarded with reputation points and other users know that you found a solution. :)

Comment: sorry Fissio. How to accept a  answer ? I am new member of Stack overflow.

Comment: Ah, I don't mind. If you want to accept this answer, press the accept-button-mark-thingy under the up and downvote buttons and the vote counter on the left of my answer. :)